# What Flash version does my Firefox 42 on 15.10 run? 19.0.0.226 or 13.1.2

Tags: firefox, flash

I use Firefox 42.0 on Ubuntu 15.10 and have only `browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash` that provides the Adobe Flashplayer Plugin installed.

```
$ dpkg -l | grep flash
ii  browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash   0.3.2-1       amd64    PPAPI-host NPAPI-plugin adapter for pepperflash
ii  pepperflashplugin-nonfree                1.7ubuntu1    amd64    Pepper Flash Player - browser plugin
```

**But I am unsure which version of Flash I am now really using?**

Various information sources give two contradicting answers **13.1.2** or **19.0.0.226**. Most strange is that one website (*whatismyflash.com*) shows both versions, depending on whether I have unblocked the embedded flash script or not.

- ### Flash version 13.1.2

  - **Firefox's internal plug-in list ("about:addons")**
    [image: Firefox's "about:addons": 13]
  - **whatversion.net** [(direct link)](http://whatversion.net/flash/)
    [image: whatversion.net: 13]
  - **codegeek.net** [(direct link)](http://www.codegeek.net/services/resources/flash-player-test-page/)
    [image: codegeek.net: 13]
  - **whatismyflash.com** [(direct link)](http://www.whatismyflash.com/) *before disabling NoScript's Flash blocking*
    [image: whatismyflash.com with Flash blocked: 13]
- ### Flash version 19.0.0.226

  - **Adobe.com** [(direct link)](https://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/)
    [image: adobe.com: 19]
  - **flashbuilder.eu** [(direct link)](http://flashbuilder.eu/flash-player-version.html)
    [image: flashbuilder.eu: 19]
  - **whatismyflash.com** [(direct link)](http://www.whatismyflash.com/) *after disabling NoScript's Flash blocking*
    [image: whatismyflash.com without Flash blocked: 19]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 19.0.0.226 flash version installed.

Trust the Adobe site. Other sites detect Linux and give wrong results.

Pepper flash was never supposed to be run in FF. It is installed using a plugin, that reports an outdated version.

There is no reason to update the plugin version every time you update Pepper flash.

Comment: And why does Firefox itself tell me the wrong version then?

Comment: The pepper flash is not originally supposed to be run in Firefox. It is a hack to install it using this plugin. The hack version is not updated.

Comment: Should that be filed as bug against Firefox? Or is it already?

Comment: I have no idea if it is reported. And it is not a FF bug, but the plugin very unimportant bug.