# How can I determine the version of Adobe Flash currently installed?

Tags: flash, versions, adobe

I would like to find the version number of Adobe Flash currently installed on my Ubuntu system.  Adobe's web site says the latest version for Linux is 26.0.0.131, but if I execute

```
apt show adobe-flashplugin
```

I get

```
Package: adobe-flashplugin
Version: 1:20170616.1-0ubuntu0.17.04.1
[...]
```

but nothing like `26.0.0.131`.

How can I see which Flash version I have installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can visit Adobe's homepage in your browser and use their little Flash version check widget.

http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/about/

[image]

Alternatively try the <kbd>Check Now</kbd> button at https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html

I [experienced](https://askubuntu.com/q/695569/367990) that this is probably the most accurate and reliable way to check the exact version.

Comment: It looks like Adobe moved that tool to https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html

Comment: @ElderGeek Moved? My old link still works as well. Yours seems to do the job too though, so I'm adding it to the answer if you don't mind.

Comment: Feel free. I must have missed that widget.

Answer (score 1):

Start Firefox and open the Add-Ons manager from the menu, then select the Plugins tab in there. It lists all installed plugins, including Flash, with their version.

Comment: This is probably correct if one uses the `adobe-flashplugin` package, but it is e.g. known to not always be accurate if you have Flash through the `pepperflash` packages. See my old question https://askubuntu.com/q/695569/367990

Comment: if using pepperflash t give perrers vers, minde says ver 26

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the version number directly from the `adobe-flashplugin` library, using a command line syntax like that: strings | grep | awk

```
strings /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libflashplayer.so|grep LNX|awk '{print $2}'
```

This will give you e.g.: 
26,0,0,151

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using that you are finding `libflashplayer.so` in `/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin` ?